# Is there a compile time flag to guard against accessing objects from StringList without using "objects"

Tags: delphi

I can't count how many times I may have erroneously done this:

```
for  i := 0 to MyList.count-1 do begin
  myobject := TMyObject(MyList[i])
  .......
end;
```

when it should be this:

```
for  i := 0 to MyList.count-1 do begin
  myobject := TMyObject(MyList.objects[i])
  .......
end;
```

Note the **objects** in the second snippet of code.

The erroneous snippet of code will run, and will obviously throw an access violation when I try to make use of myobject.  But it isn't always apparent what it is I am doing wrong.

Is there a compiler option which will guard against this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delphi has 2 ways to typecast, hardcast using `TObject(var)` and a softcast using the `As` operator.
It is a good practice to always use the `As` operator unless you are 100% sure.
In your specific example

`(MyList[i]) as TMyObject` does not compile
where as

`(MyList.objects[i]) as TMyObject` does.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes - I will have to start getting into that habit.

Answer (score 5):

No. The compiler assumes when you type-cast that you know what you're doing. It will allow pretty much any type-cast where the two types are the same size, with the notable exception of casting between integral and floating-point types.

For this particular instance, try getting yourself into the habit of using the `as` operator instead. Then the compiler will catch you when you forget to use the `Objects` property:

```
myobject := MyList[i] as TMyObject; // compiler error
myobject := MyList.Objects[i] as TMyObject; // OK
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using a TStringList to hold a string/object pair. If you are using Delphi 2009 or later an alternative suggestion is to replace your TStringList with a generic TDictionary like so:

```
uses
  Generics.Collections;
...
MyDictionary: TDictionary<String, TMyObject>;
...
for  MyObject in MyDictionary.Values do
begin
  ...
end;
```

Then the entire operation is type safe and you won't need to cast at all.

**Note:** You can't reassign the iteration variable inside a for..in loop (but you can call its methods and change the value of its properties.

Comment: +1.  TStringList gets used as a Swiss Army Object far too often.  This is probably a better answer than the accepted one, as long as the OP actually wants a string/object associative list and not a list of strings that happen to have objects attached.